# xslt - how to test a node against another node and receive output only for the nodes that tested positive

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating an XSLT that will transform an RDF Schema into HTML. I am trying to match certain controlled vocabularies with their corresponding RDF classes. The attempts so far have been unfruitful.

Here's a sample of the RDF schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:aps="rdf_apsSchema.rdf#"
    xml:base="rdf_apsSchema.rdf#">

    <rdfs:Class rdf:ID="ParentID">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Parent Identifier</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment>A unique identifier for a carrier in which the current carrier was copied
            from</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://ella.slis.indiana.edu/~shelbyjt/aps/2013-12-17.rdf#ID"
        />
    </rdfs:Class>

    <rdfs:Class rdf:ID="TapeSpeed">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Tape Speed</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment>The speed in inches per second (IPS) of a tape carrier</rdfs:comment>
    </rdfs:Class>

    <rdfs:Class rdf:ID="TrackConfig">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Track Configuration</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment>The track configuration of a tape carrier</rdfs:comment>
    </rdfs:Class>

    <aps:TrackConfig rdf:ID="FullTrack"/>
    <aps:TrackConfig rdf:ID="HalfTrackMono"/>
    <aps:TrackConfig rdf:ID="HalfTrackStereo"/>
    <aps:TrackConfig rdf:ID="QuarterTrackMono"/>
    <aps:TrackConfig rdf:ID="QuarterTrackStereo"/>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Here's a sample of the XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:aps="rdf_apsSchema.rdf#" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">

    <!-- shell for the html -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <title>schema html</title>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:RDF"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- sets up the Class Class tables -->
    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rdfs:Class"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- sets up the rdfs:Class transformations -->
    <xsl:template match="rdfs:Class">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <xsl:if test="rdfs:label">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <xsl:text>name: </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="rdfs:label"/>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>
    <!-- this is the problem code -->
            <xsl:for-each select="@rdf:ID=document('controlledVocab.xml')/controlledVocab/*">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <xsl:text>controlled vocabulary: </xsl:text>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem code (noted in the XSLT) is supposed to test whether `<rdfs:Class/@rdf:ID>` equals `document('controlledVocab.xml')/controlledVocab/*` (this file contains the `<aps:*>` elements with the prefix stripped). When it does, add "the following" to that element's section of the `<table>`.

Here's a sample of the controlledVocab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<controlledVocab xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <TrackConfig rdf:ID="FullTrack"/>
    <TrackConfig rdf:ID="HalfTrackMono"/>
    <TrackConfig rdf:ID="HalfTrackStereo"/>
    <TrackConfig rdf:ID="QuarterTrackMono"/>
    <TrackConfig rdf:ID="QuarterTrackStereo"/>
</controlledVocab>
```

Desired result:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>schema html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>label: </th>
                <td>Parent Identifier</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>label: </th>
                <td>Tape Speed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>label: </th>
                <td>Track Configuration</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>controlled vocabulary: </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Current result:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>schema html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>label: </th>
                <td>Parent Identifier</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>controlled vocabulary: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>label: </th>
                <td>Tape Speed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>controlled vocabulary: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>label: </th>
                <td>Track Configuration</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>controlled vocabulary: </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I apologize for the long post, but I wanted to be as clear as possible. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the controlledVocab.xml document (or, preferably, a minimal example thereof)?

Comment: If you're processing RDF then you'd be far better off using an RDF API (e.g. Jena) instead of trying to treat it as XML. There are many different ways to represent the same RDF graph in XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for responding. I added a sample from the controlledVocab.xml.

Comment: @ian-roberts I am currently only familiar with RDF/XML, but I will look into RDF APIs. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure th posted XSLT sample compiles? A select expression with a boolean comparison `=` should give an error.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I just checked. The "Current result" that I posted is what is outputted when I pair the RDF/XML sample with the sample XSLT, though that doesn't mean that the boolean comparison `=` is actually doing anything.

Comment: So it is XSLT 2.0 you use. But that for-each does not make sense, use `xsl:if` instead. That comparison expression also does not make sense as you compare the id with empty elements so I guess you want want to use `@rfd:ID` on the right side of the expression as well.

Comment: I don't get this. First, the result I get is not the result you claim. More importantly, I don't see why the result needs to be what you say it should. And what does *add "the following"* mean??

Comment: @michael.hor257k I apologize for being unclear in my question. I'm not sure why our results were different. What I meant by _the following_ was `for-each` (yes, I understand that `if @test` was the correct syntax now, but `for-each` was giving some sort of result, so I went with it in the question) `rdfs:Class`, when `@select` matches, output "`<tr><th>`etc.".

Comment: @michael.hor257k Also, the answer you gave definitely helps out. It looks like the key portion of what I was missing was the `name()` at the end of the `xsl:if test` (that and incorrectly using `xsl:for-each`). Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the question is not clear. See if this can get you oriented. It tests if the current class id appears in the list of elements children of controlledVocab. If yes, a table cell containing "positive" is added to the current row:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:aps="rdf_apsSchema.rdf#" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">

    <!-- shell for the html -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <title>schema html</title>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:RDF"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- sets up the Class Class tables -->
    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rdfs:Class"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- sets up the rdfs:Class transformations -->
    <xsl:template match="rdfs:Class[rdfs:label]">
        <tr>
            <th>label: </th>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="rdfs:label"/></td>
            <!-- this is the problem code -->
            <xsl:if test="@rdf:ID = document('controlledVocab.xml')/controlledVocab/*/name()">
                <td>positive</td>
            </xsl:if>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```